# Why do I get null in data parmeter of onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-camera, onactivityresult

I use the following code to take picture from the android camera, after taking the pic onActivityResult is called with data parameter equals NULL.

Code -

```
public void getpic(View v){
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            //...
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.example.myfirstapp.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);

            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);//REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO
        }
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have permission on the manifest?

Comment: Add Permission in Manifest and also if you are using Android version 6 you have to get runtime permission @S.L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE):

> The caller may pass an extra EXTRA_OUTPUT to control where this image will be written. If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is not present, then a small sized image is returned as a Bitmap object in the extra field. This is useful for applications that only need a small image. If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is present, then the full-sized image will be written to the Uri value of EXTRA_OUTPUT.

You provided `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. Your photo should be written to the location you provided in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. Your `data` extra on the response should be `null`.